# css divide width 100% to 3 column

Tags: html, css

I have a layout where I have 3 columns.

Therefore, I divide 100% by 3.

The result is obviously 33.333....

My **goal is** perfect **1/3 of screen**.

### Question:

How many numbers after dot can CSS handle to specify 1/3 of width ?

e.g. `33.33333` `(n=5)` ← how many `n` can css handle

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="c1"></div>
    <div id="c2"></div>
    <div id="c3"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#c1, #c2, #c3 {
    width: 33%; // 1/3 of 100%
}
```

Is there a better way to divide by 3?

Comment: You may use 33% for the divs you need and add two additional divs between each two of them, each 0,5% wide. This way, the divs are equally sized and you don't run into floating point problems.

Comment: I think this thread will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: just use 33% two times and for the third 34% - noone will recognize. of course just in case, you want do deviate from your original plan of "perfectness"

Comment: The theoretical precision of CSS is irrelevant: the screen can only draw in whole pixels.

Comment: Here's [an interesting post on floating point numbers in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300264/1846192). It seems browsers are free to interpret, there isn't really a spec/standard.

Comment: Decimal places at lower widths are to bo avoided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: I think you should let the browser handle it, and leave the fractions in there (width: 33.33333333%)

Comment: @Joshua things can get messy, if you design something for a narrow (33%) column, and then it's recomposed in a wide (34%) column.

Comment: This [link][1] will help you in best way.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676881/how-to-create-multiple-columns-in-a-div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to represent 1/3rd of 100% in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158735/best-way-to-represent-1-3rd-of-100-in-css)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A perfect 1/3 cannot exist in CSS with full cross browser support (anything below IE9). I personally would do: (It's not the perfect solution, but it's about as good as you'll get for all browsers)

```
#c1, #c2 {
    width: 33%;
}

#c3 {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: As I wrote above, I'm worried that such solution may produce problems. For example if the column id 33% of a fixed width area, then someone may design text to fit there nicely, but when it's moved to a wider 34% column, the text lines may break in wrong places.

Comment: I don't believe this is the right way to achieve it. Irregularity doesn't feels right to the eye, it makes the difference

Comment: +1 I think it's a "good" solution, i have the same problem and i solved with this.
it's just work width some kind of "issue".. for my 3 image it's work pretty good =)
But indeed, it's not the correct solution, but it's the easy-short solution

Comment: @YannChabot the difference is less noticable if you make the middle one 34% instead of the side ones. It may actually help making the middle ones "pop out" a bit if that's the goal.

Comment: @Babydead why not going width: calc(100%/3); ?

Comment: @YannChabot yes, I do that. But if you  need to support old browsers, that won't work.

Comment: @Babydead for you browser you can do 33.3333%, and one 33.3334% that would already be better

Comment: @YannChabot I tried that before but it gave me a 1px white edge.

Comment: As far as I know, you can have up to 16 decimals, but doing it with just 2, therefore 33.33%, gets the job done just fine.

Answer (score 136):

As it's 2018, use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) - no more `inline-block` *whitespace* issues:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#wrapper > div:first-of-type { background-color: red }
#wrapper > div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: blue }
#wrapper > div:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: green }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="c1"></div>
  <div id="c2"></div>
  <div id="c3"></div>
</div>
```

Or even [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) if you are creating a grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
}

#wrapper>div:first-of-type { background-color: red }
#wrapper>div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: blue }
#wrapper>div:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: green }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="c1"></div>
  <div id="c2"></div>
  <div id="c3"></div>
</div>
```

---

Use **CSS** `calc()`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 33.33%; /* as @passatgt mentioned in the comment, for the older browsers fallback */
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  display: inline-block;
}

div:first-of-type { background-color: red }
div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: blue }
div:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: green }
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3q5buaL/)

---

References:

- [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)
- [MDN `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
- [Can I Use `calc()`](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: The problem with this method is it's not supported by anything below IE9. If it's only being use internally on machines running anything that does support it then it's fine. If it's being used in a large scale production it's not.

Comment: That's why I put the [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc) link. If the OP doesn't need older browser support, `calc` will do just fine ( for a **pure CSS solution**).

Comment: I know this solution, just like BenM said, I am looking for more cross-browser solution. For example it will be shown in android aswell, there for I can't use CALC function. But Idea is good. +1

Comment: insert width: 33%; before the calc width, if its not supported by the browser, it will fallback to the 33% solution which is almost good.

Comment: `display: inline-block` is not good for grid system, if you have space between your divs, last div go to next line.

Comment: @ghanbari see the first link in the reference section.

Comment: worked for me in 2020. not sure of cross browser support at point in time of may 2020 but it works in chrome

Answer (score 24):

How about using the CSS3 flex model:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="c1">c1</div>
    <div id="c2">c2</div>
    <div id="c3">c3</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper{
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;

    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;

}

#wrapper div{
    -webkit-flex:1;
    flex:1;
    border:thin solid #777;

}
```

Comment: This has the horrible side-effect that when you're working with rows and you end up with an uneven number, it'll stretch the last row to 100% :)

Answer (score 10):

Using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFRDa/), you can play around with the `width` of each div. I've tried in both Chrome and IE and I notice a difference in width between `33%` and `33.3%`. I also notice a very small difference between `33.3%` and `33.33%`. I don't notice any difference further than this.

The difference between `33.33%` and the theoretical `33.333...%` is a mere `0.00333...%`.

For arguments sake, say my screen width is `1960px`; a fairly high but common resolution. The difference between these two widths is still only `0.065333...px`.

So, further than two decimal places, the difference in precision is negligible.

Answer (score 10):

```
.selector{width:calc(100% / 3);}
```

Answer (score 8):

In case you wonder, In [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) templating system (which is very accurate), here is how they divide the columns when you apply the class .col-md-4 (1/3 of the 12 column system)

CSS

```
.col-md-4{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

I'm not a fan of float, but if you really want your element to be perfectly 1/3 of your page, then you don't have a choice because sometimes when you use inline-block element, browser can consider space in your HTML as a 1px space which would break your perfect 1/3. Hope it helped !

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone is still looking for the answer,

let the browser take care of that. Try this:

- `display: table` on the container element.
- `display: table-cell` on the child elements.

The browser will evenly divide it whether you have 3 or 10 columns.

**EDIT**

the container element should also have: `table-layout: fixed` otherwise the browser will determine the width of each element (most of the time not that bad).

Answer (score 2):

Just to present an alternative way to fix this problem (if you don't really care about supporting IE):

A soft coded solution would be to use `display: table` (no support in IE7) along with `table-layout: fixed` (to ensure equal width columns).

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434923/divide-a-page-in-8-perfect-fluid-columns).

Answer (score 2):

I have found that **6 decimal places** is sometimes required (at least in Chrome) for the 1/3 to return a perfect result.

E.g., 1140px / 3 = 380px

If you had 3 elements within the 1140 container, they would need to have a width set to 33.333333% before Chrome's inspector tool shows that they are at 380px. Any less amount of decimal places, and Chrome returns a lesser width of **379.XXX**px

Answer (score 2):

**2018 Update**
This is the method I use `width: 33%;` `width: calc(33.33% - 20px);` The first 33% is for browsers that do not support calc() inside the width property, the second would need to be vendor prefixed with -webkit- and -moz- for the best possible cross-browser support.

```
#c1, #c2, #c3 {
    margin: 10px; //not needed, but included to demonstrate the effect of having a margin with calc() widths/heights
    width: 33%; //fallback for browsers not supporting calc() in the width property
    width: -webkit-calc(33.33% - 20px); //We minus 20px from 100% if we're using the border-box box-sizing to account for our 10px margin on each side.
    width: -moz-calc(33.33% - 20px);
    width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
}
```

tl;dr account for your margin

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do it in CSS, but you can calculate a pixel perfect width with javascript. Let's say you use jQuery:

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="col1"></div>
   <div id="col2"></div>
   <div id="col3"></div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function(){
   var total = $("#container").width();
   $("#col1").css({width: Math.round(total/3)+"px"});
   $("#col2").css({width: Math.round(total/3)+"px"});
   $("#col3").css({width: Math.round(total/3)+"px"});
});
```

Comment: If the container width was 100px then this still wouldnt work as as Mike W pointed out you can only measure in full pixels.

Comment: I said "pixel perfect". Of course you will never be able to cut a pixel in 3... But with this solution, each divs will have the same maximal width.

Comment: Ahh my understanding of pixel perfect was wrong then! I get what you mean now.

Comment: This would also cause them to wrap on occasion when the `.round`ing goes up.`.floor` would prevent this.

Comment: div's are block level element's, so we need to make them inline block first

Comment: what the hell kind of abomination is this, js to control css?