# div not spanning page width

Tags: html, css

I've got 3 divs floating left inside a container div. The container has a width of 100%, the 3 inside divs have a width of 33%. There is no padding/margin on the divs or body, yet still the container div isn't spanning the entire page, forcing the inside divs to overlap. Please help, I can't seem to find an answer here that works for me.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#left,
#middle,
#right {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350" height="350" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350" height="350" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350" height="350" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to add html and css snippets for us to have a guide...

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise we won't be able to help. As a quick notice is the width of the body `100%`? If you want to span across the page width you could try setting the width of the items to `33vw`.

Comment: Please post your code, so we can check it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine for me

Comment: Sorry, new here, code should be up now

Comment: To get you started: your ID's are invalid. IDs should not start with a number. Correct those and your divs will start floating.

You don't need `width: 100%` on a `div` unless it is positioned `absolutely`, `fixed`, or floating `left` or `right`. Divs naturally expand to fill all horizontal space.

You don't need `margin` or `margin: auto` on your container. Its not centred and by default it has no margin anyway.

Comment: I've just used numbers for a quick example.  I've followed the rest of your advice and it still isn't working for me.

Comment: Justin, did you try setting the position of container div to relative or absolute? In addition to this, width:100% for the container style, try to add the position property as relative or absolute, and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi Dania, position absolute fixed it. The container now spans the entire page. There is still a white space on the right side though since each inside div has a width of 33%, leaving 1% white space. Would you happen to know of a resolution to this or do you think I should post that as a separate question?

Comment: Good, I will post that as an answer, regarding the percentage, what about trying something like 33.333%? I found good answers to the percentage problem, I will post them in the answer too. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin, In addition to setting the width of the container to 100%, try to set the position to absolute or relative, like this,

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute; /*or relative, whatever solves it*/
}
```

As you said dividing the body into three equal divs each of width 33% would leave some white space. You may try something like, width=33.3333%

Also, the answers in this questions are really helpful,
[css divide width 100% to 3 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781713/css-divide-width-100-to-3-column)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Make sure the body has a width of 100%.

CSS

```
html, body {
  100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The only difference I see is that you've added a 100% width to html as well, which hasn't worked for me :/

Comment: You are using number as ids and that is not valid. Must begin with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute must begin with a letter. For the class attribute how ever, there is no such limitation. You could try this:

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    background: green;
}

.box {
    width: 33%;
    float:left; 
    background: red;
    
}



body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350" height="350" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350" height="350" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350" height="350" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this and it's still not working for me. When I run it and inspect the element the container width is 1903px and the page width is 1920px. Still getting white space on the right side of the container.